# Sequence in set notation, as a plot, recursion, and discrete function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, graphing-functions, recursion

I've been working through a study guide provided to me by my professor when I stumbled across a question I don't know how to solve. She didn't cover it in class, and when I went into tutorials to get help, the TAs didn't explain it well. I left more confused than I went in. Any help/explanations would be extremely appreciated.

> *Write the following sequence corresponding to the following set -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6... in set notation, as a plot, recursion equation, and discrete function.*

All I got from the TA was that my answer should(?) have (-1)<sup>n</sup> in the set notation, as that would make the above sequence oscillate. Again, they were very unclear, so I don't know if I misheard the above statement. Thank you for reading!

Edit: I now understand how to write it as a recursion equation and a set, but I'm confused about how to graph it. Do I plug the values from the given set into the recursion equation and plot that? Also, what is the difference between the discrete function and the plot?

Comment: Could you answer the question if the sequence was $2,4,6,8,\ldots$?

Comment: I'm not sure what "corresponding to the following set (-1,2,-3,4,-5,6...)" means since I'm used to seeing sets using curly brackets to list integers, but your TA is correct in that you should have a $(-1)^n$ in your answer. You may list out the terms of $n(-1)^n$ from $n=1$ and onwards and see what you get.

Comment: @Henry, unfortunately not.

Comment: @Accelerator, sorry about the brackets, I mistyped. Would the set notation be something like {n|n(-1)^n,nez} then or would it simply be {-1,2,-3,4,-5,6...}

Comment: To write it as a discrete function, you need to find an expression (in terms of $n$) that gives the $n^th$ term of the sequence when you evaluate it at $n$.  So, something like $f(k)=(-1)^k$  (clearly this is not the correct expression, just an example of what you are going for).

Comment: @SelrachDunbar thank you!

Comment: I don't know what "nez" means, but no, you wouldn't write $\left\{-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,\ldots\right\}$ because that's just listing the elements. The set-builder notation is $\left\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n(-1)^n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$. @MaeLevees